# Navigation bar in IBM Connections for Profiles and Files application is hidding

Tags: ibm-connections

First of all, from the time I deployed IBM Connection navigation bar (this one that lists the applications: home, profiles, blogs and etc.) worked correctly. But some time ago it started to go away(hide) when I switch to Profiles or Files apps. In all the other applications it is  working like a charm(visible).

So, possible correlation:

1. some time ago I've applied CR3 update;
2. still trying to integrate IBM Connections to WebSphere Portal
   (configuration of SSO and all the stuff connected to authorization
   from both sides: WP and Connections servers);

Any tips on how to resolve the problem?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at your custom.css file / or customization details.  also check to see that your log files in SystemOut.log and see if it tells you what is happening in the css aggregation.

Comment: Tx, @PaulBastide. There really was a problem with customization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I've discovered that the problem was with customization of headers and footers of applications (Profile and Files apps). While integrating to WebSphere Portal there were made changes to *footer.jsp* and *header.jsp* with wrong values.

In whole, there are two ways to customize look and feel of IBM Connections:

1. change look and feel for all applications (jsp files in folder *%connections_install_dir%\data\shared\customization\%app_name%\nav\templates*)
2. change look and feel for every application\feature (every .war file has *nav* directory that contains the look and feel information)

Fore more information refer to [documentation](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.0%20documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Customizing_ic40&content=pdcontent).